# Hybris java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused during ant integrationtests

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, wiremock

I have Integration test which have call to a configured WireMock server. I can see in the logs, that wiremock starts successfully, also I can curl the URL, but when I'm trying to reach URL from test via Spring Integration Gateway I get java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.

By the way, everything works fine if I start server via ./hybrisserver.sh and run test from /test.
But it's also important for me to make it work via ant integrationtests.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was connected to WireMock not being started. Аfter I managed to solve the problem with the start of WireMock on Junit tenant everything have being working as it should.